# Prove that if the $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a+b,ab)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I need to prove that:

*If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a+b,ab)=1.$*

So far I used what's given so I have:

$ax+by=1$ (I wrote the gcd of a and b as a linear combination)

and

$(a+b)u+ab(v)=1$ (I also wrote this as a linear combination)

where do I go from here?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/257434) with a [proof by Bezout](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614183).

Answer (score 10):

Assume this is not true.

Let gcd$(a+b,ab)=m>1$. Then there exists a prime number $p$ which divides $m$.

If $p\mid a+b$ and $p\mid ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $b$.

Assume that $p\mid a$. But then $p\mid a+b$ implies that $p\mid b$, and hence $p\mid\,$gcd$(a,b)$, which is  a contradiction.

**Note.** We have used the fact that: *If $p$ is a prime and $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $b$.*

Comment: How do you justify "If $p\mid a+b$ and $p\mid ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $b$."?  It's not immediately obvious how that follows.

Comment: can this question be proven using a direct proof? I'm a little confused by your proof using contradiction

Comment: @JeffSnider: If a prime $p$ divides a product $ab$, then $p$ divides at least on of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I might just want to add why it is a contradiction. By hypothesis we were given $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, and we showed that $ p \mid \gcd(a,b)  $. By substitution this implies $p \mid 1 $. But this is not possible since prime numbers $p$ are integers greater than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 9):

Below is a proof that is messier but more primitive than Yiorgos' proof. By Bezout's Identity, we have that there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$ax + by = 1.$$

Squaring both sides, we see that

$$a^2 x ^ 2 + 2abxy + b^2 y^2 = 1.$$

But notice that

$$a^2 x ^ 2 + 2abxy + b^2 y^2 = ab(2xy-x^2-y^2) + (a+b)(ax^2+by^2).$$

And hence, those same $x,y$ as above give

$$ ab(2xy-x^2-y^2) + (a+b)(ax^2+by^2) = 1.$$

So it must be that $\gcd{(a+b,ab)} = 1$.

Comment: alright it makes sense up to this part. ab(2xy−x^2−y^2)+(a+b)(ax^2+by^2).Can you explain how you factored a^2x^2+2abxy+b^2y^2?

Comment: I understand a+b(ax^2+by^2)but for the other part I would have ab(2xy)

Comment: I may have made a mistake in my algebra. Let me check it over.

Comment: no I just checked you are correct. I just wouldn't have thought to factor x^2-y^2 but if you don't add those terms it doesn't come back to the original

Comment: Ok. One can look for $u$ and $v$ such that $(ab)u + (a+b)v = 1$. Right off the bat, you can group the $2abxy$ with the first term, and follow your nose from there. If you have already seen the relevant theorems (ie Euclid's Lemma), Yiorgos' proof is almost certainly prefered. If you haven't seen Euclid's Lemma, you may want to look into its proof as its a pure gem.

Answer (score 8):

I like pushing the limits of the Euclidean algorithm. Let's do our best to elimiante $b$'s:

$$\begin{align} \gcd(a+b, ab)
&= \gcd(a+b, ab - a (a+b)) 
\\&= \gcd(a+b, -aa)
\\&= \gcd(a+b, a^2)
\end{align}$$

Since we also have $\gcd(a+b, a) = 1$, we can infer that $\gcd(a+b, a^2) = 1$.

Comment: I'm a fan of this kind of proof :):)

Answer (score 2):

We're given $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, and from Bézout's identity we have $\gcd(a,b) = 1 \iff \exists x,y: ax + by = 1$ for integer $x$ and $y$.

$1 = ax + by = ax + bx - bx + by = (a + b)x + b(y - x)$, so $\gcd(a+b,b) = 1$.  Likewise, $\gcd(a+b,a)=1$ because $(a + b)y + a(x - y) = 1$

$$ \begin{align}
1 &= ((a + b)x + b(y - x))((a + b)y + a(x -y))
\\&= (a+b)(a+b)xy + (a+b)a(x-y) + (a+b)b(y-x)y + ab(y-x)(x-y) 
\\&= (a+b)[(a+b)xy + a(x-y) + b(y-x)] + ab[(y-x)(x-y)]
\end{align}$$

So $\gcd(a+b,ab) = 1$.

Comment: Nice direct (and existentially constructive) proof.

Answer (score -2):

Proof broken into lemmas:

Lemma 1:  If $n$ is rel. prime to $a$ and $n$ is rel. prime to $b$, then $n$ is rel. prime to $ab$.

Proof:  multiply together the Bezout identities for the two hypotheses.

Lemma 2:  If $a$ and $b$ are rel. prime, then both are rel. prime to $a+b$.

Proof:  Its enough to prove if  $a$ and $b$ are rel. prime then $b$ is rel. prime to $a+b$.
We have the Bezout identity:  $a x + by = 1$.  Now add and subtract $bx$ on the left.

Conclusion:  We are given $a$ and $b$ rel. prime.  By the 2nd lemma, $a+b$ is rel. prime to both $a$ and $b$.  By the first lemma, $a+b$ is rel. prime to $ab$.