# Find integers $t,z$ satisfying $(a+b)z+abt=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let be $a,b,u,v$ integers and $au+bv=1$. I have to find integers $t,z$ satisfying $(a+b)z+abt=1$.

I think I can solve it by congruence. What do you think?

I realised $$bz\equiv 1 \quad (\text{mod}\, a)\Longrightarrow z\equiv v \quad (\text{mod}\, a)$$

$$az\equiv 1 \quad (\text{mod}\, b)\Longrightarrow z\equiv u \quad (\text{mod}\, b)$$

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The same question was asked with slightly different terminology in [If $(a,b)=1$ then prove $(a+b, ab)=1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257434/if-a-b-1-then-prove-ab-ab-1). Several of the answers there _start_ by rephrasing the question into your formulation.

Comment: But I want to know how to obtain $z$ and $t$. Not to shoe that they exist.

Comment: x @MaríaCC: At least two of the answers to the other question (by myself and Robjohn) explicitly derive formulas for the missing coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation you wrote $1=au+bv$ is the *[Bézout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)* and you can find $x$ and $y$ with the *[Eucledian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)*. More in general *Bézout's Identity* asserts that if there exists 2 integer numbers $m,n$ such that $GCD(m,n)=1$, then you can find 2 integer numbers $z,t$ such that $1=mz+nt$ with the *Eucledian Algorithm*. In this case $m=a+b, n=ab$. You can apply the *Bézout's Identity* because $GCD(a+b,ab)=1$...why? because $GCD(a,b)=1$, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257434/if-a-b-1-then-prove-ab-ab-1).