# is there a proof that if n shares no factors with m, then n+m shares no factors with m?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Examples:

4 shares no factors with 7, and 4+7=11, which also shares no factors with 7

15 shares no factors with 16, and 15+16=31, which also shares no factors with 16

21 shares no factors with 17, and 21+17=38, which also shares no factors with 17

11 shares no factors with 13, and 11+13=24, which also shares no factors with 13

Comment: There certainly is a proof; it's a standard exercise in elementary number theory. Searching the site, I'm surprised that I didn't find this question already answered.

Comment: The closest I found is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257434/if-a-b-1-then-prove-ab-ab-1

Comment: @dxiv, how did I not find that? Darn it; I need to work on my searching skills...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is a number that divides both $n+m$ and $m$, then it also divides their difference, $(n+m)-m$, which is $n$. Since we assume that $m,n$ are coprime, then $p=1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I am striving not to do that. Did you not see above where I searched the site and failed to find an exact match before posting this? Please strive to pay attention before busting people's chops.

Comment: Being one of the most common exercises in elementary number theory,* of course* it has been solved here many tens (if not hundreds) of times.

Comment: That's what I thought too! That's why I was surprised when I couldn't find it!

Comment: It's very easy to find many dupes, e.g. [this search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd%5Cleft(n%2Bkm%2C%5C%20m%5Cright)%5C%20%3D%5C%20%5Cgcd%5Cleft(n%2Cm%5Cright)%24&p=1)

Comment: I see. By using a search engine I've never heard of before, I could have found things I didn't find. Thank you for the advice. I'm basically done with this website, and I'm sure I won't be missed.

Comment: See [How to search on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/how-to-search-on-this-site/29267#29267) and [many other meta posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=approach0&searchOn=3)

Comment: @BillDubuque only if you promise to work on how you talk to people. Your original comment here was low-skill. Get better.

Comment: That's a boilerplate comment that gets posted many times. I don't have the time to customize it to every thread.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should probably word your problem more rigorously, and say what you did or didn't try yourself. Also, use MathJax to format your math statements.

Anyway, the proof is as follows.

Suppose $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n$ and $m$ are coprime, that is to say, $(n, m)=1$. This notation means GCD of $n$ and $m$ is $1$, in case you didn't know, which is an equivalent statement to "sharing no factors".

Now, let $k$ be a shared factor of $n+m$ and $m$.

Then, $k|m$ and $k|n+m$.

So, there exists some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, such that $ka = m$ and $kb = n+m$.

Substituting for $m$ in the second equation, we get $$kb = n + ka$$
$$ kb - ka = n $$
$$ k(b-a) = n $$

And since $n+m \gt m$, we know that $b \gt a$, so $b-a \gt 0$.

So, by definition, $k|n$.

Now, since $n$ and $m$ are coprime, and $k$ is a shared factor, it must be that $k|1$, which means that $k=1$.

Thus, any shared factor of $n+m$ and $m$ must necessarily be $1$, so $n+m$ and $m$ are coprime.

Also, note that $n+m$ would also be coprime with $n$ by the same logic.

Comment: This isn't really an argument by contradiction, because you haven't assumed that $k>1$. Indeed, you have proven that $k|1$, which is enough to get the desired result without appealing to any contradiction.

Comment: oops, you're right, silly mistake. Since k divides n and m, and they're coprime, naturally it has to be 1. I'll correct this.